# When exactly getApplicationContext will be assigned?

Tags: android

In my application, A is an activity which will be launched first. The code is as follows:

```
    public class A extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Here I'm checking if the user has already got registered, using shared preference. If yes, I want to fetch the version of this application and start Activity B. Other wise perform some other operation.

  if(Registered) {

    //Here, I'm trying to fetch the version of my own application.

    PackageManager manager = getApplicationContext()
                            .getPackageManager();
                    PackageInfo info;
                    try {
                        info = manager.getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext()
                                .getPackageName(), 0);
                        String version = info.versionName;

    } catch(NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }  
    }
    }
```

So, as soon as my application gets installed, this code will be executed. Here I'm getting NameNotFoundException. It is caught but still causing me some problem.

getApplicationContext cannot be null in the above code. If it was, then "manager" would be null causing null pointer exception. What might have really happened to cause NameNotfoundException?? Please help.

Comment: When you are using getApplicationContext() means it is a context for a whole application and when you are using Activity.this then it is used for particular context for that Activity...

Comment: @PiyushGupta: I know it. But how can a crash appear?? Its a corner case.For many users this code has worked like a charm. But I'm facing this problem from about 400 users. I'm actually updating my database with the current version fetched. If the exception is thrown, I've caught it, thus skipping the update code. I'm the loosing the data over here. Please help.

Comment: you may have a look to your manifest for android:versionName is not missing.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

```
 PackageManager manager = A.this.getPackageManager();
```

Comment: Is my approach wrong?? Please let me know how. I really need to know the reason here.

Answer (score 0):

Here the `Context` that should be used is `this` ,i.e the Activity Context.

Note that:

`Application Cotext : Return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process. This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.`

Comment: Although, this approach has worked on many users. But for the rest, it has not. I'd have got Null Pointer Exception if there were problems with getApplication context right? Coz, I'm using it to get the package manager.